# Is there a way to keep a copy of printed documents in guest account

Tags: windows, windows-8, printing, printer, guest-account

Is there a way to save a copy of printed documents through guest account in Windows 8.1 without guest account user's knowledge?

I need to monitor what was printed in guest account.

Comment: You'd usually have a look at the printer for that, if it supports it. But you could check Printing Properties => Ports to check whenver you can just enable the File port and it would print on both.

Comment: But for the file port, the guest will know his files are being saved!

Comment: You would of course inform your guest and not keep a copy of a document he printed without him knowing, right? After all from a privacy standpoint this could also mean legal trouble if they do find out.

Comment: The guest would be my staff and they are aware that whatever is getting printed is archived.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Printer Properties > Advanced and tick "Keep printed documents". That will prevent the printer from deleting them after they have been printed. You can then use something like [SPLVIEWER](http://splviewer.sourceforge.net/) to view the files.

Comment: Can the guest user delete those "keep printed documents"?

Comment: Just make sure guest does not have Full Control or Delete permissions on the spool folder (c:\windows\system32\spool)

Answer (score 0):

"Keep printed documents" in Printer properties works, BUT if user deletes file from queue (using printer queue dialog on client machine), files from spool folder are also deleted. Even if the user does not have delete/write permissions on that folder.